# Calculating a probability of a maximum event

Tags: real-analysis, probability, algebra-precalculus, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of IID random variabels with continuous distribution function. For each n let $E_n = \{X_n>X_i \text{ for all } i <n \}$ be the event that there is a record at time n.

I have calculated that $P(E_n) = 1/n$. I am now asked to calculate the probability $P(E_n \cap E_m)$.

The event $E_n \cap E_m$ I thought could be split into the following:

i) the maximum occurs over times $1,\ldots,m$ achieved at $m$

ii) the maximum occurs over times $m+1,\ldots,n$ achieved at $n$

these two events are independent so I got$P(E_n \cap E_m) = \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-m}$ however the answers have an additional $\frac{n-m}{n}$ - may I ask how they got this value?

Comment: Could you give more info on how you derived $P(E_n)$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yes - I used the fact that $E_n =\{ \max X_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ and the fact that each $X_n$ is identically distributed and independent, so the maximum will occur at each time $1,...,n$ with the same probability

Comment: Your definition of $E_n$ in the comment and in the question do not seem to be the same...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. $E_n = \{ X_n = \max X_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, your answer $P(E_n)=1/n$ and your reasoning is correct. For the second question,  if $n=m$, you already have the answer since $E_n\cap E_n=E_n$. Then, assume that $n>m$. Due to your reasoning, every order of first $n$ random variables is equally likely for every $n$. For simplicity, consider $P(E_6\cap E_3)$. This means that $X_3$ is the maximum of first three random variables and $X_6$ is the maximum of the first 6 random variables. First consider $X_1,X_2$, and $X_3$. $X_3$ is the largest, but for $X_1$ and $X_2$ any ordering is possible, which is $2$!. Now consider $X_4$, $X_5$ and $X_6$. $X_6$ is the largest, it must be on the very right. For $X_4$, we have 4 different possible place. So far, location of 4 variables are fixed: $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$, and $X_6$. $X_4$ cannot be on the right of $X_6$, but any other location is possible, i.e., first, second, third or forth. So basically, for $X_4$, 4 locations are possible. Suppose that we have located $X_4$. Then, similarly, for $X_5$, 5 locations are possible. In general, there are 6! orders. This means that the related probability is $\frac{2!\times 4\times 5}{6!}=\frac{5!}{3\times 6!}=\frac{1}{3\times 6}$. Note that in this special case, $m=3$ and $n=6$. Now, I think we can generalize the result. The related probability is

$P(E_n\cap E_m)=\frac{(m-1)!\times (m+1)\times\cdots\times (n-1)}{n!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{m\times n!}=\frac{1}{nm}$.